# Read text from a gif image using Azure Cognitive services

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

azure API is working for .jpg images but when i tried for gif image it show **Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'**

```
print("===== Read File - remote =====")
# Get an image with text
read_image_url = "https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/5NB2CkeM22wqFhiQSmRlJVVinEp3o2nEbZQcy6_8CCKlKst_WW25N0PcsPaYiWAASXO52hufvUAEimUd3IreGowknEXy322x5oYG3lzkBGyctLI0M3eH_w-qHH9qPqtobjpGYooM7AvyNX2CCZtcnEgu8duKlee2GGaswg=s0-d-e1-ft#https://image.e.us.partycity.com/lib/fe301570756406747c1c72/m/10/93d08fa0-c760-4d8b-8e35-ddd5308ec311.gif"

# Call API with URL and raw response (allows you to get the operation location)
read_response = computervision_client.read(read_image_url,  raw=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **CANNOT** send a gif directly to azure read api because the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/overview-ocr#input-requirements) states below:

```
Request body

Input passed within the POST body. Supported input methods: raw image binary or image URL. 

Input requirements:

Supported image formats: JPEG, PNG, BMP, PDF and TIFF.
Please do note MPO (Multi Picture Objects) embedded JPEG files are not supported.
For multi-page PDF and TIFF documents:
For the free tier, only the first 2 pages are processed.
For the paid tier, up to 2,000 pages are processed.
Image file size must be less than 50 MB (4 MB for the free tier).
The image/document page dimensions must be at least 50 x 50 pixels and at most 10000 x 10000 pixels.
```

To handle the gif you need to convert into png and then send a raw binary image for recognition as shown below:

```
import glob
import time

import requests
from PIL import Image

endpoint = 'https://NAME.cognitiveservices.azure.com/'
subscription_key = 'SUBSCRIPTION_KEY'

read_url = endpoint + "vision/v3.2/read/analyze"

uri = 'https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/5NB2CkeM22wqFhiQSmRlJVVinEp3o2nEbZQcy6_8CCKlKst_WW25N0PcsPaYiWAASXO52hufvUAEimUd3IreGowknEXy322x5oYG3lzkBGyctLI0M3eH_w-qHH9qPqtobjpGYooM7AvyNX2CCZtcnEgu8duKlee2GGaswg=s0-d-e1-ft#https://image.e.us.partycity.com/lib/fe301570756406747c1c72/m/10/93d08fa0-c760-4d8b-8e35-ddd5308ec311.gif'
with open('/tmp/pr0n.gif', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(requests.get(uri).content)

gif='/tmp/pr0n.gif'
img = Image.open(gif)
img.save(gif+".png",'png', optimize=True, quality=70)


for filename in sorted(glob.glob("/tmp/pr0n.gif*.png")):

    # Read the image into a byte array
    image_data = open(filename, "rb").read()
    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key, 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
    params = {'visualFeatures': 'Categories,Description,Color'}
    response = requests.post(read_url, headers=headers, params=params, data=image_data)
    response.raise_for_status()

    # The recognized text isn't immediately available, so poll to wait for completion.
    analysis = {}
    poll = True

    while poll:
        response_final = requests.get(response.headers["Operation-Location"], headers=headers)
        analysis = response_final.json()
        time.sleep(1)
        if "analyzeResult" in analysis:
            poll = False

        if "status" in analysis and analysis['status'] == 'failed':
            poll = False

    polygons = []
    if ("analyzeResult" in analysis):
        # Extract the recognized text, with bounding boxes.
        print(analysis["analyzeResult"]["readResults"][0])
```

Comment: @ayaz-khan, did this solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a brand new online portal provided by Microsoft to test this service, among others and [input requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/overview-ocr#input-requirements) for Read API.

Link: https://preview.vision.azure.com/demo/OCR